# touch doesn't "click" in windows 8

Tags: windows-8-preview, touchscreen

I know windows 8 is in its early stages but maybe someone has a solution for this.

I can pan and zoom things with my fingers all day but it never interprets my touches as a click (I do get the animations that go with hovering, i think). So to get around I have to resort to clicking on things with the mouse.

The other weirdness is if I hold down my finger the touch effect circle on screen shakes a lot and in the drawing program included the lines are not smooth, more like someone with shakey hands, even though I drew a smooth line.

The one thing that works correctly is the touchscreen keyboard, it seems unaffected by the rest of the problems.

Anyone else experienced or solved these issues?

Comment: Where did you get windows 8?

Comment: @wizlog The recently released [developer preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/home/).

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same issue on a toshiba tx2-1150 tablet pc. Fully updated from windows update.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with DELL studio touch laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your screen is an ntrig device, like mine is, ntrig just released windows 8 specific drivers!

http://www.ntrig.com/Content.aspx?Page=Downloads_Drivers

Answer (score 5):

Because this is what you would call alpha or pre-alpha software it may not work as expected on all hardware.

I had some strange issues, that were sometimes solved by a reboot, or a complete re-install.

It may also be specific to your particular hardware, check the Windows Update as there may be specific hardware drivers required.

If that still doesn't work see if you can find some Windows 7 drivers for your hardware and attempt to install them on your Windows 8 instance.